# How to use an array within a .txt document to create an object

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a text file with 10 arrays, 1 on each line.
The code is supposed to take one of these arrays, and use each element to create an object from a class.

Here is the code:

```
class character(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, name, lvl, hp,):
        self._name =  name
        self._lvl =  lvl
        self._hp = hp
        
    def stats(self):
        print("Name:", self._name)
        print("Level:", self._lvl)
        print("HP:", self._hp)

def venture():
    with open("Zone1.txt") as text:
        entries = text.readlines()
        search =(random.choice((entries))
        monster = character(search[0], search[1], search[2])
```

With the arrays in *"Zone1.txt"* looking like this:

*["Fish", 5, 14]*

Instead of pulling element 1, 2 & 3, it pulls the 1st, 2nd and 3rd character in the line.

Any help is appreciated and I will try to answer any question presented to me.
I also wasn't sure how to properly describe my problem, and therefore couldn't find an existing question so apologies if dupe.

Comment: You are using the whole line to construct your arguments, you need to use the `.split()` method on them to split the lines in words, then your indexing will work as expected. Edit: I had not looked well enough, looks like you need to use `json.loads()`.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your "search" line? It should be search =(random.choice(entries))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're reading from a text file, each line of the file is a string and not a list.
you can convert this string into a list using a package called `json`:

```
import json


search =json.loads(random.choice(entries))
```

Comment: It is now saying that ```monster = character(search[0], search[1], search[2])``` has a syntax error, with "monster" highlighted

Comment: @OGComputerSci can you share the exact error? I'm running these lines and getting expected output, no errors. unless you didn't copy my exact line, since you had a typo in the `search  = ... ` line. you had a redundant `(`

Comment: Redid a couple lines and it worked, thanks